Excel different loan calculator: input: principle, interest rate, *monthly payment*. Output: month that repayment is finished
Excel: My loan calculator is a little different. User inputs are start date, loan amount, interest rate and monthly payment. Output is a cell that displays the month the loan is repaid. It only needs to be +/- few months, so how it compounds is not important.
Approach #1: I have a row for each month with columns showing how payment is applied to interest and principle to give the new principle amount. That works fine – after 100 or so rows the principle goes to 0. Problem #1.1) In order to accommodate the longest scenario, I have 300 rows. That means after the row where the loan is paid off, the remaining rows show a non-sensical increasing negative balance. How to hide rows after the month the loan is repaid? Problem #1.2: how to display in a cell (off to the side, independent of any row) the month that the principle goes to zero? (I’ve been writing if() with some combo of relative and absolute references, but not successful).
Approach #2: a single formula – I have no idea of how to get started.
Any suggestions to solve the problem with either approach #1 or #2 (or other)?
Thanks.

Share some sample data and it's expected outcome. Also your current formula.

It sounds like you want to use =NPER which is a financial formula that calculates the net periods until a loan is paid off. Combine this with an EOMONTH formula and you should be able to make it work depending on the specifics of the loan. For example, a loan of 10k, with 500 payments at 5% annual interest, applied monthly would look as a follows:
=nper( 5%/12, 500, -10000) note the negative loan amount.
Wrapping this in an eomonth formula gives how many months from a given date will the loan be paid off:
=eomonth( today(), nper( 5%/12, 500, -10000) )
Giving the answer 12/31/2025. This figures the last day of the month, however many periods the nper calculates.
